# Calculating $U = e^{i\tau\cdot\alpha}$ for $SU(2)$ transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, group-theory, linear-algebra

How can I prove that if $U = e^{i\tau\cdot\alpha}$ with $\alpha=\alpha(\sin\phi,\cos\phi,0)$, then
$$
U= \begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\alpha & e^{i\phi} \sin\alpha \\ 
- e^{-i\phi} \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha  \end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
$$

I attempted a proof but it didn't find the desired formula: what I did was:

$$ U = e^{i\tau.\alpha} = 1 + i~ (\tau. \alpha) = 1 + i \tau_1 \alpha_1 + i \tau_2 \alpha_2 + i \tau_3 \alpha_3 = \begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1  \end{array}\right) 
+
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0  \end{array}\right) \alpha \sin\phi  +
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -i \\ 
i & 0  \end{array}\right) \alpha \cos\phi =   
 \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \alpha(\sin\phi-i\cos\phi) \\ 
\alpha(\sin\phi+i\cos\phi) & 1  \end{array}\right) 
 \\ =  
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -i\alpha~ e^{i\phi} \\ 
i\alpha~ e^{-i\phi} & 1   \end{array}\right) \end{equation} $$
which is not the required result.

Comment: $e^{i\tau.\alpha} = 1 + i~ (\tau. \alpha)$ wait a minute there...

Comment: You have to expand up to all orders not just the first.

Comment: You must note that $\:\boldsymbol{\tau}=(\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3)\:$ are the Pauli matrices since in most textbooks the symbols
$\:\boldsymbol{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)\:$ are used.

Comment: There is another simple way to derive this result. I'll write it if You need.

Comment: For pity's sake, don't ever expand! Use the proper [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) correctly...

Comment: Hint : Using the commutation properties of Pauli matrices, try to find what is the expression
$$
\left(\boldsymbol{\tau}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}\right)^{2}=\left(\tau_{1}n_{1}+ \tau_{2}n_{2}+\tau_{3}n_{3}\right)^{2}
\tag{01}
$$
with $\:\mathbf{n}=(n_1,n_2,n_3) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\:$ a  unit vector , $\:\Vert\mathbf{n}\Vert=1\:$, then what is
$$
\left(\boldsymbol{\tau}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{a}\right)^{2}=\left(\tau_{1}a_{1}+ \tau_{2}a_{2}+\tau_{3}a_{3}\right)^{2}
\tag{02}
$$
with $\:\mathbf{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\:$ in general.

Comment: Combine your results with the infinite series expansion of $\:e^{x}\:$ (as in kryomaxim answer). Expand once in order to understand how the formula in Cosmas Zachos comment was derived. Don't use this formula as given a priori.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compute $e^{i(\tau.\alpha)} = 1 - \frac{1}{2!} (\tau.\alpha)^2 + \frac{1}{4!}(\tau.\alpha)^4+ i(\tau.\alpha)-\frac{i}{3!}(\tau.\alpha)^3 + \frac{i}{5!}(\tau.\alpha)^5 + \dots$ and use the property of the $SU(2)$ generators (remind the Clifford Algebra).

Comment: This is very complicated for me, any clarification how make this and reach for required U .. I know the commution relation for SU(2) genertors : $[\frac{\tau^i}{2}, \frac{\tau^j}{2}]=i\epsilon_{ijk} \frac{\tau^k}{2}$

Comment: Couldn't you just calculate  $(\tau\cdot \alpha )^n $ explicitly? Because the matrix in the brackets is off diagonal,  it's straightforward

Comment: There is a representation of $SU(2)$ Group where Generators satisfy $\tau_i \tau_j + \tau_j \tau_i = 2 \delta_{ij}$ , in other words, you can use These Generators like you would treat it as commutative elements. Example: $(\tau_1 sin \phi + \tau_2 cos \phi)^2 = sin^2 \phi + cos^2 \phi = 1$

Comment: That works too, of course.